# Warning: A path must be pathname + search + hash only, not a full UR - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error:

```
Warning: A path must be pathname + search + hash only, not a full URL like "http://www.shadyab.com/category/tehran/fast_food"
```

---

```
   <li className="hidden-xs hvr-shutter-out-vertical">
           <Link to={serverConstants.DOMAIN_URL + 'category/tehran/fast_food'} >فست فود</Link>
  </li>
```

---

my constants files.

```
export const serverConstants = {
    DOMAIN_URL: "http://www.shadyab.com/",

}
```

if I remove `serverConstants.DOMAIN_URL`, my url appended to current url.

for example:

current url:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/tehran/foreign_restaurant
```

now if I click on below link:

```
<Link to={'category/tehran/fast_food'} >فست فود</Link>
```

my url appear like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/tehran/category/tehran/fast_food
```

my route:

```
<Route path="/category/:city/:category" component={Category} />
```

my react router version:

```
"react-router": "^3.0.5",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Link`, you don't need to specify the domain name, just the Route path like

```
  <li className="hidden-xs hvr-shutter-out-vertical">
       <Link to={'/category/tehran/fast_food'} >فست فود</Link>
  </li>
```